# How do I build apk for android API 21 using Ionic 3? It keeps building for API 23 even though I changed the target sdk to 21 in config.xml

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, sdk, command-line-interface

I am  running the command : **ionic cordova build android**

Following are the other details:

ionic version: 3.19.0

cordova version: 8.0.0

in config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="21" />
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Have you managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
ionic cordova platform rm android

ionic cordova platform add android@6.1.1
```

You can use any custom version number

Comment: I've done this as well. Although I had written: "ionic cordova platform add android@5.0". Later on, when I build, it says "android@5.0 not added to project. "

Comment: In your android studio do you have the sdk installed for this version ?

Comment: Yes, I have the sdk installed.